# Article about Judaism.SE in the YU Commnetator

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Judaism.StackExchange.com and Embracing Online Torah Communities](http://www.yucommentator.org/2012/04/judaism-stackexchange-com-and-embracing-online-torah-communities/)

The web version of the YU Commentator was just published, and it includes a very positive article about Judaism.SE! The article was written by the Technology editor of the Commentator  (and I contributed a tidbit or two). The print version will be out after Pesach.

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much for making this happen!

Comment: The article has been Hirhurim'd:
http://torahmusings.com/2012/04/news-links-90/